# Spring boot cannot compile views in 1.5.8 release

Tags: spring-boot

Environment:

1. STS-3.9.0.RELEASE
2. Java Version: 1.7
3. Spring Starter Project, web

I have a spring boot project that works fine with 1.4.2 release but not with 1.5.8. When I change to 1.5.8, it stops compiling JSP and prints the page as it is.

Here are my files:

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.educo</groupId>
<artifactId>sprboot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>sprboot</name>
<description>Event tracker project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>    
</project>
```

### src/main/java, com.educo.Application.java

```
package com.educo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

### src/main/resources, application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

welcome.message: Hello
```

### src/main/java, com.educo.controller

```
package com.educo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/body")
@ResponseBody
public String body() {
    System.out.println("there");
    return "Hello world!";
}

// /param?name=ashutosh
@RequestMapping("/param")
@ResponseBody
public String params(@RequestParam String name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}

// /path/ashutosh
@RequestMapping("/path/{name}")
@ResponseBody
public String paths(@PathVariable String name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}

// /path-view/ashutosh
@RequestMapping("/path-view/{name}")
public String pathView(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "path-view";
}
}
```

### src/main/webapp, /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

```
<b>Welcome</b> to my website
```

### src/main/webapp, /WEB-INF/jsp/path-view.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"
%>

Hello ${name} by path view
```

On changing to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I get the error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 29 23:58:06 EDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

No error gets printed on tomcat console.
I tried to read the changelog for 1.5.8 but could not find anything on this. What I'm missing here?